# how to display result vertically in pop up

Tags: php, mysql

[image]

The result displays like in the image. I want to display it vertically. How can I do it ? I want the result to be like this:

[image]

I am using bootstrap modal to display this vertically. Please help me.

```
<div class="modal-header">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
  <h6 class="modal-title">Please Select Your Destination</h6>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <?php
    $data="select * from destination";
    $res=mysql_query($data);                            
    while($recor=mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
    {
      $id=$recor['id'];
  ?>
  <h4><font color="red"><?php echo $recor['destination']; ?> </font> </h4>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>  
  <ul>
    <?php           
      $data1="select * from sub_destination where destination_id='$id'";
      $res1=mysql_query($data1);
      while($recor1=mysql_fetch_assoc($res1))
      {
        $subid_count=$recor1["id"];
        $counts=mysql_query("select * from hotels where sub_destination_id='$subid_count'");
        $counts_res=mysql_num_rows($counts);
    ?>

    <li class="col-md-2 col-sm-1"><a href="search-result.php?sub_id=<?php echo $recor1['id']; ?>&main_id=<?php echo $recor['id']; ?>" style="color: inherit;"><div class="dest-list"  ><?php echo $recor1['sub_destination']; echo "&nbsp; (".$counts_res.")";?></div></a> </li>

    <?php 
      }
    ?>
  </ul>
  <div class='clearfix'></div>
  <?php     
    }
  ?>
```

Comment: recommendation: do not mix SQL queries and HTML code in same page

Answer (score 1):

Both class "col-md-2" and "col-sm-1" in class attribute of list tag  contains style property "float:left" that will display list tag value into horizontal line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex-box like this :

```
.modal-body{ //your wrapper
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px; //specify height for the wrapper

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: stretch; 
}
```

But the problem is the carriage return in the ul, i think you should to split ul :  increment a variable line by line and when the column have the required number of lines you create a new ul. If any one have an alternative solution...

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem some time ago.

Had list of car makes and had to have multicolumn menu.
I solved this by using multicolumn layout that CSS provides.

This solution does not work for all browsers but suppoort is quite good ([caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn)) and as IE has stopped supporting all other IE versions than edge ([read all about it](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3123303)), maybe this will become cross browser solution some day.

Here is my solution:
[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4bofaybc/)

The main bit is the div holding the ul tag:

```
div {
    column-count: 4;
    -moz-column-count: 4;
    -webkit-column-count: 4;
    column-rule: 0.1rem outset #aaaaaa;
    -moz-column-rule: 0.1rem outset #aaaaaa;
    -webkit-column-rule: 0.1rem outset #aaaaaa;
    width: 800px;
}
```

Comment: but sir it didnt work on firefox any soluation is there then provide it .

Comment: It does work. At least with my Firefox 44 and 43. Screenshot for 44 in response. Check your version and update in case required